# How many unit paths in $\mathbb R^3$ of length $9$ starting from the origin?

Tags: plane-geometry

I have a general formula for the number of unit paths to be $a+b+c \choose a$ (which I'm not even certain is correct). I know $a+b+c=9$ but how do you determine what the bottom should be? I believe the answer should be a summation but am not sure of what. Is it the summation of $9\choose k$ where $k=1...9$?

Answer (score 0):

What are the points are reachable by unit paths of length $9$?
They are precisely the points $(a, b, c)$ such that $a + b + c = 9$.
Moreover, given a point $(a, b, c)$, we know how many unit paths there are from the origin to $(a, b, c)$.
It is just an arrangement from the multiset containing $a$ "left arrows", $b$ "up arrows" and $c$ "diagonal arrows". This is just the multinomial coefficient $a + b + c \choose a \ b \ c$. 
So the answer is
\begin{gather}
\sum_{a + b + c = 9} {a + b + c \choose a \ b \ c}.
\end{gather}
Does this formula look familiar to you?

Comment: Yes thank you! So there isn't a way to simplify the multinomial coefficient to a binomial one like in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: You should think about the binomial formula. Recall that $(x + y)^n  = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} x^k y^{n - k}$. The multinomial formula is a generalization of the binomial formula.